# Array PHP to object spreadsheet

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I have an array PHP and I want to convert in an object SpreadsheetPhp; 
I use a library about SpreadsheetPhp.
I have tried with some method but if, for example, I wrote:

```
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($result, "Xls");
```

and $result is a array, I have the error because `$result` isn't a object. 
I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter() must be an instance
>   of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet, array given, called in
>   C:\xampp3\htdocs\sincro\parts_europe.php on line 166 and defined in
>   C:\xampp3\htdocs\sincro\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php:47
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp3\htdocs\sincro\parts_europe.php(166):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter(Array, 'Xls') #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp3\htdocs\sincro\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php
>   on line 47

Thanks

Comment: No the problem is that you are using that method incorrectly https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/

Answer (score 0):

`$result` must be an instance of **PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet**, try to make it as an object not an array like the code below :

```
$result = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($result, "Xls");
```